# How do I download Facebook Ad creative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

we download buckets of stats (conversions, spend etc.) but also need to download the Ad creative itself, including:

- Headline
- Text
- Images (including Positioning, or just the visible part of the image)

I've scoured the Facebook API docco and can't find how/where to do this.

Even better would be an API call that returns the creative of the "top" 5 Ads e.g. by Conversions.

Many thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creative copy and image is available via the [adcreative's ID](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcreative/v2.2#read) or its associated [connection objects (page post)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcreative/v2.2#obtaining_objects).

You'll need the adcreative IDs which you may have received along with the conversion and spend stats, if not then you can get them via their [campaigns](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcampaign/v2.2#connections) from the API.

I'm not sure what you mean by "positioning". Do you want to know if it's a right-hand rail ad or a newsfeed (mobile or desktop) ad? If so you'll want to pull the [ad type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcreative/v2.2#create) (certain ads only work in certain places) and where the ad was targeted ([read targeting from the adset](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adset/v2.2#read)).

Finally, try out Facebook's Graph API Explorer to get a feel for the API and retrieving the data you seek: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Many thanks for the response, I'll look into it shortly. Regarding Positioning, in the Edit Your Advert dialog, there is a Reposition button for changing which portion of the image is displayed (the Viewport). I need this in order to know how to show the image.

Answer (score 1):

also, if you want to get an ad's creative(s) *from an ad*, use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/<AD_ID>/adcreatives
```

which returns a list of creative ID's like

```
{
  "data": [
    {
       "id": "<AD_CREATIVE_ID>"
    }
  ]
}
```

which you can then query for `fields=body,object_type,title` etc.
HTH

Comment: I used this solution, and added called /<ad_id>/adcreatives?fields=body,thumbnail_url

Answer (score 0):

Use the `adcreatives` edge from an Ad:

`GET /v2.10/{adgroup-id}/adcreatives HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com`

Required permissions: ads_read

Returns:

`{
    "data": [A list of AdCreative nodes],
    "paging": {}
}`

Docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/adcreatives/